# Como colocar en el eje x la fecha del registro con Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

como puedo acomodar el eje x de esta gráfica para que muestre la fecha como tal y no me coloque consecutivo el año:

Si se fijan en la gráfica el eje x esta imprimiendo valores de años que están mal, y yo en las series específicamente en la data ya estoy imprimiendo la fecha que quiero mostrar, pero no me funciona.

Por otro lado la idea es que si varios registros de la data tienen la misma fecha el lo deje en la misma columna del eje como se puede apreciar en la gráfica tenemos 3 registros uno debajo del otro por lo que pertenecen a la misma fecha.

Cualquier ayuda me serviría de mucho.

Muchas gracias adjunto gráfica:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'scatter',
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'DESECHOS OCTUBRE'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Periodo: 2019-10-01 AL 2019-10-14'
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            enabled: true,
            text: 'Fecha'
        },
        startOnTick: true,
        endOnTick: true,
        showLastLabel: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Vida (km)'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: 100,
        y: 70,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: Highcharts.defaultOptions.chart.backgroundColor,
        borderWidth: 1
    },
    plotOptions: {
        scatter: {
            marker: {
                radius: 5,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true,
                        lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                    }
                }
            },
            states: {
                hover: {
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                pointFormat: '{point.x} dia, {point.y} km'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'VRPS',
        color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
        data: [
        [2019-10-01, 93545], 
        [2019-10-03, 67501],
        [2019-10-04, 91114], 
        [2019-10-04, 103484], 
        [2019-10-04, 97441],
        [2019-10-05, 81783], 
        [2019-10-06, 102288], 
        [2019-10-09, 97437],
        [2019-10-09, 69516]]

    }, {
        name: 'V063',
        color: 'rgba(119, 152, 191, .5)',
        data: [[2019-10-11, 99805]]
    }]
});
```

```css
caption {
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 font-family: 'Verdana';
 font-size: 1.2em;
 color:#555;
}

table {
 font-family: 'Verdana';
 font-size: 12pt;          
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
 margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fff;
}

table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #FCF9F9;
}

th {
 font-weight: 600;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas convertir tus fechas a `UTC` asi:

```js
var myDateFormat = '%e/%m/%y';

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'scatter',
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'DESECHOS OCTUBRE'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Periodo: 2019-10-01 AL 2019-10-14'
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            enabled: true,
            text: 'Fecha'
        },
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {          
          millisecond: myDateFormat,
                second: myDateFormat,
                minute: myDateFormat,
                hour: myDateFormat,
                day: myDateFormat,
                week: myDateFormat,
                month: myDateFormat,
                year: myDateFormat
        },
        
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Vida (km)'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: 100,
        y: 70,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: Highcharts.defaultOptions.chart.backgroundColor,
        borderWidth: 1
    },
    plotOptions: {
        scatter: {
            marker: {
                radius: 5,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true,
                        lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                    }
                }
            },
            states: {
                hover: {
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                pointFormat: '{point.x} dia, {point.y} km'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'VRPS',
        color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
        data: [
        [Date.parse('2019-10-01'), 93545], 
        [Date.parse('2019-10-03'), 67501]]

    }, {
        name: 'V063',
        color: 'rgba(119, 152, 191, .5)',
        data: [[Date.UTC(2019,10,11), 99805]]
    }]
});
```

```css
caption {
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 font-family: 'Verdana';
 font-size: 1.2em;
 color:#555;
}

table {
 font-family: 'Verdana';
 font-size: 12pt;          
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
 margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fff;
}

table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #FCF9F9;
}

th {
 font-weight: 600;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Hola alanfcm esta muy bien el ejemplo pero en las fechas esta colocando mes 11 y seria mes 10, como podría corregir esa parte?

Comment: Cuando conviertas tus fechas a UTC, tienes que restarle 1 al mes.

Comment: ok, pero se puede hacer algo para que esto Date.UTC(2019-10-01) quede con las rayas y no con comas Date.UTC(2019,10,01), 93545 ya que ese es un valor que lo traigo directamente desde la base de datos y la imprimo como una variable en php. ejemplo: <?php echo $fechadese; ?>

Comment: Intenta con `Date.parse()`, ya edite mi respuesta.

Comment: Listo ya me funciono perfecto muchas gracias por tu ayuda.